# Can't find out why i'm getting an injector error

Tags: angularjs

I am getting an error on injecting my collections factory, but can't figure out where I went wrong:

Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0/$injector/unpr?p0=%24scopeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%20%3C-%20collections

```
  'use strict';

    var thangular = angular.module('thangular', ['ngAnimate']);

    thangular.config(function ($interpolateProvider,$httpProvider) {
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[').endSymbol(']]');
        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    });

    thangular.factory('collections', ['$scope', '$http', '$q',
        function ($scope, $http, $q) {

            return {

                all: function () {
                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    var request = $http({
                        method: 'GET',
                        url: '/collections.json',
                    });
                    request
                        .success(function (result) {
                            deferred.resolve(result.content);
                        })
                        .error(function (error) {
                            deferred.reject(error);
                        });

                    return deferred.promise;
                }

            };
        }
    ]);

    thangular.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', 'collections',
        function ($scope, collections) {

            collections.all().then(function (data) {

                console.log(data);

            });

        }
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you shouldn't inject `$scope` in factory declaration. Just change

```
thangular.factory('collections', ['$scope', '$http', '$q',
```

to

```
 thangular.factory('collections', ['$http', '$q',
```

Factory declaration should not dependent upon controllers `$scope`.

Comment: Ok, just tried it and it looks like it's solved. That is interesting though. I've injected $rootScope many times before, and that works. Thanks!

Comment: `$rootScope` would work in a factory, but factories don't have their own scope so `$scope` cannot be used